# Meteor JS install on Ubuntu 14.04.x

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, meteor

Does Meteor JS require installation of NodeJS on Ubuntu before installation of Meteor?
I have tried install Meteor on Ubuntu 14.04 without install NodeJS and it doesn't work. I followed the instructions which I found on this link 
[Meteor Tutorial](https://www.meteor.com/install).

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you need to install nodejs before install Meteor.

```
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get install curl
$ curl https://install.meteor.com | sh
```

For Node.js

```
$ sudo apt-get install python-software-properties python g++ make
$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:chris-lea/node.js
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get install nodejs
```

Best Regards.

Comment: Thanks Alex. Thanks for quick replay.

Comment: Actually you don't need nodeJS installed. That curl magic should install nodeJS for you. What you just need is curl.